# shopping cart rule based on custom attribute

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart, free-shipping, ee-1.12

I would like to create a rule based on 2 attributes :

- first attribute : enable free shipping, yes/no value
- second attribute : date end of free shipping promotion, date value

then I will create a rule that say basically if all items in shopping carts have free shipping enabled and end date in the future, then give free shipping, otherwise, proceed as usual.

Any way to do that like that?

PS : i know how to do it with just a rule, but I insist on using attributes, because I want as well to display a small promotion warning in the product page, I therefore do not want each time to update both rules and attributes (to avoid discrepancies).

Magento EE 1.12.0.0

Answer (score 3):

You can, just set the attributes to be used for promotional rules

[image]

after which you can use it in your `shopping cart price rules`.
The date should also be an attribute set to be used for price rules. The rule will allow you to use the date

[image]

Comment: that looks like a total good idea. Will try that.

Comment: ok, then I can get it to work with the Yes/No part and your solution, but for the date I can not use it properly. I have to set in the rule a date, the thing is that date should be today...

Comment: updated the answer, is this what you mean?

Comment: not exactly, I would like to put a date : Free shipping until, and if the date is passed, then false, if the date is not passed, then true, it basically means that in my rule, the date is today, or more exactly the result of `today()` function

Comment: The screenshot above shows an attribute that is used with a date. You will need to add your own attribute offcours bit in principle it works. I might not exactly understand what you are trying to do then

Comment: in your example, I set a date in the rule and compare it to the attribute value. I want to set it in the attribute and compare it with today's date. the rule would then be "Special Price From Date is Not Passed". I do not know whether I am clear enough

Comment: Ah ok, now I get it. Ok that will require extending the promotional rules. I'm not sure it's actually that easy to do

Comment: OK, thanks for your help, that is indeed quite a bit of work if need to overwrite with an extension.