# how to show multiple discounts for same product Magento 1.9.3.3?

Tags: discount, category-products, catalog-price-rules

There are same products which are new and some of them have discounts depending on their state of usage.

So, for  `1 week used product get 5%  discount`, and  `2 weeks 10%` etc.

Obviously `it's the same product (SKU)` but how can I show these products with their discounts on  **one Discounted Products page** ?

If **I have a Product X new (full stock)** but also `one with 5% off and 2 with 10% off`

How can I get those with the discounts listed in one list?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible for single SKU as magneto discounts work's on the SKU basis. Also please specify Magneto version.

Comment: But making new products for every discount is not ideal. Also since the stock comes from the same product.

Comment: Please let me know, how are you presenting these two option to the customer for same product, is it configurable product?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution it might help you this might not be a correct way but it's a way around.

```
1. You can create custom attribute with "used for promo rule condition" as Yes.
```

Then go to catalog price rules and add rules over there you will find the custom attribute in the new rule condition dropdown.

```
2. Specify the price over there and also the discount amount.
```

hope this helps you [this is the link to the demo that is more detailed explained](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/42998/55519)